# не работает сессия во Flask python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

Хочу залогиниться под своими `email` и `password`. Но в `account['id']` получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Я понимаю, что имеется ввиду, но не понимаю как исправить. Как получать `id` и `email` именно того пользователя, который хочет залогиниться? Как это решить?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s', (email, password))

        account = cur.fetchall()

        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account[0]
            session['email'] = account[1]
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        else:
            return 'Email/Password incorrect!'

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template('profile.html', email=session['email'])
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: у вас опечатка в  account['id], должно быть  account['id']

Comment: @dhvcc, исправил, но к сожалению тоже самое

Comment: На каком моменте выдает ошибку? Покажите лог, уточните проблему. Так же обновите вопрос без опечатки

Comment: @dhvcc, обновил. посмотрите

Comment: На какую строку ошибка?

Comment: @Viewed, на эту `session['id'] = account['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что вы понимаете разницу между методами

- `fetchall()` – число записей в виде упорядоченного списка
- `fetchmany(size)` – число записей не более size
- `fetchone()` – первая запись

Тогда здесь предположу ожидание следующего результата

```
account = cur.fetchone()
# (id, email)
```

Следовательно вместо обращения по ключу, использовать индекс

```
session['id'] = account[0]
session['email'] = account[1]
# Вместо 
# session['id'] = account['id']
# session['email'] = account['email']
```

## Обновление

> я делал так, но тогда получал только первого пользователя из моей базы
>   данных
>
> Как получать id и email именно того пользователя, который хочет
>   залогиниться?

Вы запрашиваете данные сессии из формы. Но никак не используете их в запросе к базе.

```
email = request.form['email']
password = request.form['password']
...
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data')
```

Неизвестно какие имена столбцов вашей таблицы. Предположим, что они совпадают с ключами формы. Тогда вам нужно составить следующий запрос:

```
cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = {email} AND password = {password}')
```

Где `{email}` и `{password}` значения от `request.form['email']` и `request.form['password']`

Comment: я делал так, но тогда получал только первого пользователя из моей базы данных

Comment: @abby Потому что `fetchone()` – первая запись из результатов `SELECT`. Ваш `SELECT` забирает всех из таблицы `users.data`. Нет условия проверки `WHERE` на совпадение с введенными данными. Отсюда получение неверного пользователя.

Comment: обновил код. посмотрите. все равно получаю такую ошибку. `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: @abby верните `fetchone` и сделайте `print(account)`, чтобы понять, что получаете и как к этому обращаться.